# WCF Architecture question - Fast response and Queing

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, msmq

I have a simple WCF need - basically clients running in isolation and a server so really client/server intially.

WCF helps us decouple the service layer and practise a SOA approach for scale.

All we are doing on the server (per call/multiple concurrency) is writing to a db and then performing some IO for another system which will have immediate use for - but this might change as (unknown) requirements build.

Speed: We need the service to be literally quick as possible: 1 second is OK - 2 is slow - and some errors need to be sent back immediately.

I was considering using server async patterns, queues (MSMQ), Azure, to allow the service method to queue and return quickly. NB However, some processing might be 'online' in the WCF service (db write) with an immediate return with response/error, others could be offline (IO). Disadvantage: This requires a means to callback the client if there is a show-stopper error and design and development scales accordingly.

i) Although WCF allows for the service I see the technology as providing an interprocess comm channel and perhaps the actual service operations should run in win services. Eg. WCF writes to a db which a long-running service polls and picks up. As the system gets bigger and bigger some operations may be genuine fire and forget long running - which complete or are needed hours after. We can take these out of the immediate loop. This is true decoupling even if it slows us down. A WCF method can't pass to a service unless it is calling another WCF service and can't call a windows service!

*From an architectural viewpoint, is it OK to have some operations complete and return, and others pass to a true bus or service (by some mechanism)? Am I over-engineering this?*

ii) As all the operations of db and IO will take say 1 or 2 seconds max I feel I might just call the service aysnc from the client and wait for it to return and then marshal back to the client UI. This is also simple. This might prove a wrong decision in the long run but having said that, all service layer ops would be in a seperate dll so that these could be called by another service for later scale. A method call could be marked as immediate or queue for processing, say.

*Thoughts*?

Answer (score 0):

> From an architectural viewpoint, is it
>   OK to have some operations complete
>   and return, and others pass to a true
>   bus or service (by some mechanism)? Am
>   I over-engineering this?

It is OK, all depends on detailed requirements.

Thought #1

Have operations return unique request ID and one operation that provides status by request ID.

Thought #2

Have operations return result if they are done within X number of seconds or request ID.